# How to specify HTTP expiration header? (ASP.NET MVC+IIS)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, iis, http-headers

I am already using output caching in my ASP.NET MVC application.

[Page speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) tells me to specify HTTP cache expiration for css and images in the response header.

I know that the Response object contains some properties that control cache expiration. I know that these properties can be used to control HTTP caching for response that I am **serving from my code:**

```
Response.Expires
Response.ExpiresAbsolute
Response.CacheControl
```

or alternatively

```
Response.AddHeader("Expires", "Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT");
```

The question is **how do I set the Expires header for resources that are served automatically, e.g. images, css and such?**

Comment: IIS 7...but I may not have access to all settings in IIS, this site is hosted

Comment: You can set it in IIS: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rakkimk/2007/07/09/iis7-how-to-enable-content-expiration/

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Found it:

I need to specify client cache for static content (in web.config).

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" 
      cacheControlMaxAge="12:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />
    </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

from http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/staticContent/clientCache

Comment: how is this different than setting a far future expire date in IIS ??

Comment: not sure if there is any difference - feel free to check the differences in HTTP traffic :) The mentioned approach has an advantage that it is possible to alter the caching behavior without configuring IIS (e.g. on shared hosting)

Comment: What if, one of the image changes before the cache expiry date. How do we initial the 302 request for that image?

Comment: @sameer if it's a different image, use a different name, or use a cache-buster (querystring with date of file)

Comment: Also, for anyone curious, when you hit refresh on the browser, it will do an if-modified-since request for each file... if you navigate, you'll see the cache response.

Comment: i tried this but i have a issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704618/asp-mvc-expire-headers-not-set-for-static-contents) is my question,  expire header is not set

Answer (score 31):

If you want to do it from code for a resource that you're returning (ie. not a static file being served from IIS), you're better off using `Response.Cache`:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddYears(1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
```

I know that's not exactly what you're asking for, but I found this question via Google and figure others might like this answer as it's related to the APIs you show in the original question text.

Comment: Shouldn't that be DateTime.UtcNow? If not, can you explain how the browser knows what the local time of the server is? (Update: actually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849744/should-i-use-datetime-now-or-datetime-utcnow-in-httpcookie-expires-and-httpcache answers this question)

Comment: Good question. As you discovered, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [mini static content delivery](http://mscd.codeplex.com) project. :)